# Using regex to delete extra empty lines of a text

Tags: regex

I have a text like this:

```
.class
{
   margin:5px;


   border: none;




   font-size: 12px;
}
```

And then I want to remove extra lines, I use the following regex for that to replace:

```
/^\s*$/
```

It selects all empty lines, but what happens? It keeps at least one lines between two other line, I mean, it results in the following text:

```
.class
{
   margin:5px;

   border: none;

   font-size: 12px;
}
```

what I need is a regex to remove any space between two lines, and only keeps a newline character, which is something similar to this:

```
.class
{
   margin:5px;    
   border: none;    
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something that will work on Unix and Windows, use this:

Search: `(\r?\n)(?:\r?\n)+`

Replace: `$1` or `\1`

**Explanation**

- `(\r?\n)` captures to Group 1 an optional carriage return, and a newline. This allows us to match either Windows-style `\r\n` sequences or Unix-style `\n`
- `(?:\r?\n)+` matches one or more additional line breaks
- We replace the match with the content of Group 1

Comment: it works...thanks..can you edit your answer with a description of the the "search regex". Thanks